# PHP: syntax error, unexpected '[' when using array_map

Tags: php, function, parse-error, array-map, php-parse-error

I've been creating a php script for a project and have been running it on my development server which is running PHP 5.4.17

I need to move it over to my production server which is running PHP 5.4.19

When using the `array_map` function on my development server I got the results I needed with no problem.

On my production server I get the parse error:

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /path/to/script/ on line 219`

My code used was:

```
$arr = array_map(
    function($results_titles, $results_image, $results_summary, $results_dates, $results_links) {
        return ['title' => $results_titles, 'image' => $results_image, 'summary' => $results_summary, 'date' => $results_dates, 'link' => $results_links];
    },
    $results_titles, $results_image, $results_summary, $results_dates, $results_links
);
```

Comment: You've confused PHP and JS syntax) In PHP array initialized with: `array(...)`, not `[...]`

Comment: I don't remember since which version using `[array_elements]` was valid, maybe the problem is there, try using the classic structure: `return array('title => $result_titles, etc...);` I would keep using that syntax for a while, just in case xD

Comment: Are you 2000% sure it's running on 5.4 on your server?

Comment: @hind Nope, PHP supports this syntax now as well.

Comment: @hindmost since 5.4.0 you can use `[]` directly for the arrays too. OP, I think you are on a version prior to 5.4.0, check this link, your code should be valid on >5.4 http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php

Comment: @deceze However the given error msg tells that `[]` syntax is invalid (on OP's env.)

Comment: @hind Maybe so, but *generally* PHP supports that syntax!

Comment: BTW, @Sal: `function ($title, $image, $summary, $date, $link) { return compact('title', 'image', 'summary', 'date', 'link'); }` - much more concise.

Comment: @aleation your answer worked the best here. Thanks. I'm still not sure why it didn't work on my production server when phpinfo() output that version. But return array(); worked great. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The new array syntax comes up with PHP 5.4.

So make sure your php version in your server is >= PHP 5.4

***Note: the cli and the web server(eg: apache) could run different version of php.***